# Web Driver: TypeError: browser.saveScreen is not a function

Tags: webdriver-io

Using WebDriver.io in the command land to automate visual tests of our website.

Was working last week.

Today, I receive: `TypeError: browser.saveScreen is not a function`, referring to the `saveScreen` function in:

```
const HomePage = require('../pageobjects/home.page');

describe('Mega Menu page', () => {

beforeEach(async () => {  
    await browser.maximizeWindow()
    await browser.setTimeout({ 'pageLoad':15000000 })  
    await browser.refresh()
 });
afterEach(() => {
    browser.execute('window.localStorage.clear()');     
    browser.deleteAllCookies()
    browser.execute('sessionStorage.clear()')    
});
it('should save megaMenu  page section 1 screenshots', async () => { 
    await browser.url('/en-gb/'); 
    await browser.pause(4000)  
    await browser.saveScreen('UKmegaMenu-01', { });
});
```

I've run `npm update`, but the issue remains.

Pointers appreciated.

Comment: are you using [multiremote](https://webdriver.io/docs/multiremote/) by any chance?

Comment: No @Yarin_007, not using multiremote.

Answer (score 0):

The [list of functions](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser) for the `browser` object doesn't have a function named `saveScreen`. It only has `saveScreenshot`.

from https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/saveScreenshot

> saveScreenshot:
> Save a screenshot of the current browsing context to a PNG file on your OS. Be aware that some browser drivers take screenshots of the whole document (e.g. Geckodriver with Firefox) and others only of the current viewport (e.g. Chromedriver with Chrome).

Comment: saveScreen [is valid](https://github.com/wswebcreation/wdio-image-comparison-service/issues/44). I have since cloned this project into a different local directory, run `npm install` and the error no longer occurs.

Comment: @Steve The list of functions for the `browser` object doesn't have a function named `saveScreen` https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser

Comment: Unusual. `saveScreen` doesn't generate an error though.

Comment: @Steve isn't "browser.saveScreen is not a function" an error?

Comment: I no longer receive the error...

Comment: @Steve so saveScreen works now?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the error is thrown because the browser.saveScreen function is not present in the version of Webdriver.io that you are using.

You may want to check the documentation for the version of Webdriver.io you are using to see if the saveScreen function is still supported and if so, if there have been any changes to its usage.

If the function has been deprecated or removed, you may need to find an alternative method to save screenshots in Webdriver.io or consider using a different automation tool.